# Running Docker images as Jenkins slave

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a Jenkins Master running in Windows as Local system. I have Jenkins slaves running as Docker containers in a VM in the same Machine.

Everything is working OK, I just want to know are there any gains in memory consumption or ressources if I'm going to run parallel jobs in the master and slaves or should I just use parallel steps using pipeline in Master?

Comment: I cannot comprehend the entire situation from this alone, but at a glance if you're running all from the same machine, it comes down to the same thing .. The only real way to find out is to test it.

Comment: Upvoting because some stackoverflow peeps need to CHILL THE HELL OUT with the down voting. This is fine,  for chrisakes. Our rep is bad enough already without being jerks.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can go with the assumptions that running something inside docker does not add a significant amount of resource consumption, neither CPU nor RAM, compared to starting the same process directly.

Also, it is usually good to optimize only if necessary.

So pick the Jenkins configuration that seems cleanest/nicest/most elegant to you. If you run into trouble, *then* look for a solution. As you are running everything on a single physical machine, thinking too much about performance is a moot point anyways, it's not like the solution will scale in any direction, anyways. But getting to know Jenkins, and finding good configuration solutions which you may be able to apply in a "real" environment later is certainly possible in this way.